# react serve works, but deploying to github pages or heroku fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to deploy this repo

https://github.com/stepseazy/checkers/

to this website

https://stepseazy.github.io/checkers

However, I'm getting 404 errors. I also tried heroku. It does work when I serve the build locally. Not sure what's wrong. Please help!!!

Comment: How are you deploying? It looks like none of your bundle chunk or other resources are accessible/found.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to distinguish your dev environment and your production one. On dev mode, you run `npm start` that does things (as instructed in `package.json`) and act as a local server and *serves* you project on `http://localhost:3000`. You simply cannot use that in production mode on Github or Heroku.

You need to deploy the *built* version, running `npm run build`. It will create a javascript file in a `dist` folder. You might want, on Github, create a `gh-pages` branch, build this production ready file on it, create an `index.html` file that serves it, and commit that.

I'm no expert on Heroku but it might be a slightly similar case (run post-deploy scripts that build your app and serve it through an index.html file).

Hope that help.